# Html video should stop at first frame

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a .mp4 video in my html page. I applied autoplay to that video, it stops at ending frame. My concern here is this video should come back at first frame once the video playing done. Can anybody please suggest what should i do to do this. Thanks

Comment: You should try and show us your html code. that way it will be easier for us to point out the problem

Comment: Direct from video tag you can't achieve this. you must have to do this by javascript

Comment: @UmangPatwa can you please share a link if possible even with javascript. it may helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the video to loop and start again you can use the 'loop' attribute:

```html
<video controls loop>
  <source src="yourVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  ...
</video>
```

If you want to detect the end of the video and do something else, like restart the video you can use the end of video event in JavaScript:

```js
$("#yourVideo").on("ended", function() {
   //Add whatever you want to do when the video ends here
   video.pause();
   video.currentTime = 0;
   video.play();  //You may not need this - experiment on different browsers
   video.pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Must include `js` file I am using `CDN`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function () {
     document.getElementById('Sample').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);  
          function myHandler(e) {
               var video =document.getElementById('Sample');
               video.currentTime = 0;
               video.pause();
          }
     });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<video src="video.mp4" id="Sample" autoplay>
      video not supported
</video>
```

Answer (score -1):

By javascript and assuming that you know the framerate of your video:

```
function goFirstFrame () {
    var video = document.getElementById('videoId');
    var frameTime = 1/25; // If your video is 25fps
    video.currentTime = 0 + frameTime;
    video.pause();
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps nitpicking (depending on the video content), but `currentTime=0` is the first frame. The code above will set it to *second* frame (if fps is 25 or lower).